# Traco DC-DC Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

[image]I am using [THN 15-1215N](https://assets.tracopower.com/20190902135529/THN15N/documents/thn15n-datasheet.pdf) for generating 24V from 12V input. Since this module has a second output(Negative) can I connect this to the ground to obtain only a single output?

Edit:-
I am using the module for designing a board, for future purposes i have included few 0R resistor for trimming the output.

Comment: Draw a diagram of your proposal. There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar.  Use the Custom Component to draw the converter. Double-click to edit its properties.

Comment: I have updated the question with schematic i am using

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Are you sure? The datasheet claims 1600V input-output isolation.

Comment: @Hearth You're right, I was wrong, I didn't look careful enough. Indeed the DCDC is isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should be, according to their [app note](https://www.tracopower.com/products/browse-by-category/find/thn-15n/3/)

Yours is a single output model, I guess.

[image]

It is clear that single output model, has only one output channel. Additionally you have a trim input without a common.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can i use common ground for input and output?

Comment: I guess, no. In the app note has 3kV caps between them, why don't you read the app note?

Comment: you can, do that, no problem. 1KV is the mavimum difference allowed, 0 is perfectly acceptale.

Comment: @Jasen Can you point to that solution, where is this documented?

Comment: this is common to all isolatd supplies, they can be used non-isolated if isolation is not needed.

Comment: So, yes the datasheet says it's an isolated DC DC converter, you may connect -Vout (or even +Vout, whichever you want ) to GND.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can ground the negative output and get +24 from the positive output

Or ypu can ground the positive output and get -24 from the negative output.  or any other setup so long as the difference between input and output potentials does not exceed the isolation limit. which seems to be about 1000V

think of the output like a 24V battery in series with an ideal diode there's many different ways it can be used.

Comment: I have unique problem. I am feeding 12V to this module and and generating +24V . I am also using the input 12V for the some (ULN2003AD) chip which operates on +24V and +12V( I have provided Voltage selection jumper on design). So my doubt is that can the input voltage ground(12V) and the ground to which i am connecting -Vout pin to generate +24V can be same ?

Comment: yes they can be the same. there is very little restriction when you use an isolated DC-DC converter.  a non-isolated converter like https://www.banggood.com/XL6009-Module-p-87541.html would require the 12V gound and the 24V gound both be the same.